# How to select data yearly from stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like sp_extraction '01/01/2002', 'current date' so basically the stored procedure select data from joined table and in the where clause there is date range condition i.e. date > fromdate (01/01/2002) and date < todate (current date).

My requirement is to select the data between the given date year by year rahter than just selct...from...where date < and >.... So obviously I think I need loop or cursor. However the SQL instance I am using has limited tempdb space so need to optmize the process to the best efficiency.
Hope someone can give me some hints what I can use in my stored procedure and give some sample scripts if possible?

Comment: How about calling the SP for each year you want data from?

Comment: ... or change the stored procedure?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks guys. The purpose from the requirement was just run the procedure once rather than run the procedure by each year repeatly. So it will be more like change within the existing procedure add loop to select date for each year one by one. That's what user want i think. And Thanks marc_s I will try use other prefix rather than sp_ prefix

Answer (score 1):

You should **NOT** use a cursor or a loop! Instead - use a proper **set-based** approach that works best with all relational databases.

To limit to a given year - define the beginning of the current year you're interested in, and the beginning of the next year as an upper threshold, using two `DATE` variables and then just do a `SELECT` with those two `DATE` variables used in a `WHERE` clause - something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectYearly (@Year INT)
AS BEGIN
    -- define two variables for the beginning of the current year, and the beginning of the next year
    DECLARE @BeginningYear DATE
    DECLARE @BeginningNextYear DATE

    -- set the two variables - use the ISO-8601 format YYYYMMDD to be safe from any language/regional settings
    SET @BeginningYear = CAST(CAST(@Year AS CHAR(4)) + '0101' AS DATE)
    SET @BeginningNextYear = CAST(CAST(@Year+1 AS CHAR(4)) + '0101' AS DATE)

    -- do whatever you need to do, and use the two variables to limit the selection 
    -- use the "YourDateCol >= @BeginningYear AND YourDateCol < @BeginningNextYear" syntax
    -- to select all data for that given year that you're interested in
    SELECT 
        (list of columns)
    FROM
        (your table IN question)
    WHERE
       YourDateCol >= @BeginningYear AND YourDateCol < @BeginningNextYear
END
```

Comment: Hi marc_s thanks for the script. But this will need run the procedure multiply times by each year repeatly until to current year. But user want the procedure only run once and paramter cannot change so guess I need to ientify the year gap between start date and end date then run loop within?